# Получение Мета-данных мр3 файла по прямой ссылке

Tags: java, android, mp3, metadata

Имеется прямая ссылка (гугл диск) к мр3 файлу, в приложении есть список, на каждый пункт своя ссылка и кнопка скачать. Хотел прежде скачивания по ссылке получать мета-данные, чтобы отображались имя мр3 файла, его продолжительность и размер. Мета-данные из мр3 файлов в локальном хранилище могу извлекать посредством `MediaMetadataRetriever`:

```
try {
        MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

        // Если путь локальный, проблем не возникает,
        // а если прямая ссылка извлечение мета-данных не срабатывает
        mmr.setDataSource(pathAudioFile);

        String trackTime = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);

        long duration = Long.parseLong(trackTime) / 1000;
        long hours = duration / 3600;
        long minutes = (duration - hours * 3600) / 60;
        long seconds = duration - (hours * 3600 + minutes * 60);

        @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
        String timeString = String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
        holder.tvTotalTrackTime.setText(timeString);

    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
```

А вот как извлекать их из еще не скачанных файлов по прямой ссылке не знаю, гуглил, ничего не нашел. Есть ли решения?

Comment: гляньте [тут](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever)

Comment: @TimurVI установил арк-демо, программа не может получить данные. Скидываю ссылку в телеграм, там пока не скачал сразу пишется имя трека и продолжительность, неужели без сторонних библиотек это невозможно осуществить?